# How do I create an Entity Framework data model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

There is two ways to create the an Entity Framework data model:

1. By creating the classes in code.
2. By choosing an existing database.

I really still don't know what is the difference between them and which is better, or which is more maintainable?

How do I add an EF model to a project that has a separation of concerns between the presentation, business logic, and data model?

Comment: Check out the "Which workflow should I use" topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907#model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that if you're extending an existing application that uses a database then a database-first approach might be more appropriate (if you have your DBA create the database, for example). If you are creating an application from scratch and you're the one designing the database (and app logic) then it might be easier to go with code first.

But then again this separation is not absolute, because even if you have a database you can generate your POCO classes using [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d).

I tend to go with code-first approach for all new applications that I build. I set up my entity classes and the relationships I need between entities. I find that when you're building an application and you need to modify your database (add a table or add/remove column here and there) it's very easy to do that with code-first approach. I find that I work on different machines, then I just pull the latest code from version control repository on another machine, run `Update-Database` in `Package Manager Console` to update/recreate the database. That way I don't have to copy the database from machine to machine.

For example, let's say you're working on an application that needs to be slightly modified for each client. You could go with code-first because it's easier to tweak the classes as needed for each client and then simply update the database.

`How do I add an EF model to a project that has a separation of concerns between the presentation, business logic, and data model?`

Let's say in your `MyProject.DAL` (Data Access Layer) project add a reference to Entity Framework with NuGet package manager. In your `Models/` directory create your code-first models and add the `DbContext`-derived class (if you're going with code-first) or add `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` (***.edmx** extension) (if you're going with database-/model- first) and take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Daniel, mikhairu and Filix.

I reached this:

All the answers up there are right, but the design depends on my needs.
So, if I choose Code-First, then that doesn't mean it's wrong because my needs require the Code-First.
Neither if I choose Database-First, then that doesn't mean it's wrong because my needs require the Database-First.

So, the whole process depends on my needs.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is to do database first, then update EDMX with current db schema.  Doing code first means that you will model your entities in Visual Studio, your EDMX then update your db.  The reason I prefer db first, is that in my opinion its easier to screw up code first.  There's been times when T4 didnt build out entities properly and screwed up whole EDMX.  With db first, its not an issue, just wipe out your EDMX and do update from db and you will be back in action in no time.  Screwing up code first EDMX can potentially change your db schema and that would be a huge problem.  This is simply my preference, although I don't believe there's a right or wrong way of doing it.  I know many people prefer code first which is fine, but I like to do db first.

Comment: I don't think what you're describing is what is usually meant by "code first". I might call starting in the EDMX designer as "model first". Code first means writing plain classes and deriving the schema from that and (optionally) fluent (e.g. code-based) mappings.

Comment: Maybe I didnt explain it to correctly.  You can do your classes either by hand or though edmx, but code first means you create your entities in the solution first, whereas db first you would create db then update your entity model.

Comment: Well, I don't think your criticism applies to code first.

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't believe I was criticizing code first at all, just stated my preference.